# Want to know a way to split String based on delimiters passed as parameters without using regex

Tags: java, string, split

I want a way to split a given String based on multiple delimiters. I do not want to use regex to achieve this as I have to use enum to pass delimiter as a parameter in string split method.

I used the enum and passed the delimiter as parameter and stored the result in a List which works fine for a single delimiter. But I am unable to solve the next part where I need to split the remaining String based on another delimiter.

For Instance :

Initial String = "one.two#three"

```
new StringSplitter("one.two#three",Separator.dot.toString(),Separator.hash.toString())    
returns: {“one”, “two”, “three”}
```

I am able to somehow get "onetwo three" or "one" & "two three" as output but not all sub strings together in one list. Please refer to below code on what I have tried so far.

```
public class StringSplitter {

    public String givenString;
    public String givenSeparator;
    public String anotherSeparator;


    public StringSplitter (String givenString, String givenSeparator, String anotherSeparator) {
        this.givenString=givenString;
        this.givenSeparator=givenSeparator;
        this.anotherSeparator=anotherSeparator;
    }

    public List<String> SplitMethod() {

        List<String> FirstSplitList  = Arrays.asList(givenString.split(givenSeparator));

        System.out.println(FirstSplitList);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String ch:FirstSplitList) {
            if(ch.contains(anotherSeparator)) {
                sb.append(ch);  
            }

        }

        String newStringtoSplit = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(newStringtoSplit);
        List<String> newString = Arrays.asList(newStringtoSplit.split(anotherSeparator));
        System.out.println(newString);

        return newString;

    }   

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        StringSplitter var = new StringSplitter("one.two#three",Separator.dot.toString(),Separator.hash.toString());
        var.SplitMethod();
    }



    enum Separator{

        dot {
            public String toString() {
                return "\\.";
            }
        },

        hash {
            public String toString() {
                return "#";
            }
        },

        comma {
            public String toString() {
                return ",";
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I would like the code two handle atleast two delimiters and work in below fashion when the String is "one.two#three" and delimiters as "." and "#" the output should be a List containing [one two three].

Comment: Are you aware of the Guava [Splitter](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter) class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to replace the other separators with the first one. 
It also works if you also have the separator repeated like "one.two.three"

```
public class StringSplitter {

public String givenString;
public String[] separators;

public StringSplitter (String givenString, String... separators) {
    this.givenString=givenString;
    this.separators = separators;

    if(this.givenString == null || this.separators == null || this.separators.length < 1 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid arguments passed");
    }
}

public List<String> splitMethod() {

    String newGivenString = givenString;

    // replace all other separators with the first one
    if(separators.length > 1) {
        // skip the first separator
        for(int idx = 1; idx < separators.length; idx++) {
            newGivenString = newGivenString.replaceAll(separators[idx], separators[0]);
        }
    }

    List<String> splitList  = Arrays.asList(newGivenString.split(separators[0]));

   System.out.println(splitList);

    return splitList;

}   

public static void main (String[] args) {

    StringSplitter var = new StringSplitter("one.two#three",Separator.DOT.toString(),Separator.HASH.toString());
    var.splitMethod();

    var = new StringSplitter("one.two#three,four",Separator.DOT.toString(),Separator.HASH.toString(),Separator.COMMA.toString());
    var.splitMethod();

    var = new StringSplitter("one.two#three four",Separator.DOT.toString());
    var.splitMethod();
}



enum Separator{

    DOT {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\\.";
        }
    },

    HASH {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "#";
        }
    },

    COMMA {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ",";
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hi ViBort, thanks for the amazing response. Using varargs and replacing all the separators with the first one worked really well. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

This works for any number of separators. It assumes the input is in the correct format.
`String.indexOf()` returns the index of the first occurrence of the parameter value

```
public static List<String> split(String input, Separator... givenSeparators) {
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<>();
    int s1=0;
    for (Separator s:givenSeparators)
    {
        s1=input.indexOf(s.toString());
        result.add(input.substring(0, s1));
        input=input.substring(s1+1);
    }
    result.add(input);
    return result;
}
```

I don't use regular expressions so no need to escape the dot:

```
dot {
    public String toString() {
        return ".";
    }
},
```